# Quadratic equation too hard

Tags: quadratics

I am trying to solve a quadratic equation very hard. Is there any other way to solve this without quadratic formula?

$$ x^2(-BE(F+C)^2(G+C)(A+C))))+x(C(F+C))\left [ EBA(D-H)-(G+C)(A+C)(B(D-H)+D(F+C)) \right ]+(ABC^2(D-H))=0 $$

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H are just constants...i want to solve for x.

I tried quadratic formula but lost myself...

Is there any trick? Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace the coefficients with $K,L,M$, solve using quadratic formula and substitute back. I don't think there is a way which would be much easier.

Comment: It's hard to prove, but I'd assume that knowing two of the coefficients of the above would not yield the other; this would mean that you'd *have* to use the quadratic formula. It might simplify some, but probably not.

Comment: @Wojowu I had done it but didnt get anything...just a lot of calculations and then i got a really hard root

Comment: @MiloBrandt what do you mean with knowing 2 of the coefficients of the above would not yeld the other?

Comment: You could complete the square using substitutions for the coefficients, like Wojowu suggested. Ostensibly, though, you'd still be doing the quadratic formula. For equations that are as complicated as this, the quadratic formula is basically the only way to go.

Comment: @pipita I mean that you could presumably choose A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H such that the quadratic had the form $ax^2+bx+c$ for any given a, b, and c. That is, your quadratic represents a general quadratic, which makes the prospects for simplification less hopeful. (However, if you just plug everything into the quadratic formula, it is possible that you'd find a simplification)